# Apply Knockout bindings in Jquery .each loop after Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js, each

I have a bunch of elements applied to single page. They are .ascx controls that have data specific to each control but in the same format/display.

I need to create a knockout binding of a certain viewmodel to each of these elements for them to work properly. So currently I wait for the dom to load and loop through each of the elements applying a new binding like so:

```
$(function () {
    var target;

    $(".wrapper").each(function (index) {
        target = this;

        $.ajax({
            url: getLink,
            data: 'AllData',
            async: false,
        }).done(function (data) {
                vm = new myViewModel(data);
                ko.applyBindings(vm, target);
        });           
    });
});
```

The problem lies with this Ajax call being nested in the middle of the .each loop. If I set `async: false` it executes correctly, but it feels sluggish and the page won't allow a lot of other interaction to work until this loop is done executing. If I set `async: true`, the target keeps iterating while the Ajax call is going out so by the time it's coming back all of those bindings are being applied to one element and I'm getting the error: `You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure that `target` is a captured local variable.  You've declared it outside of the `.each()` loop, meaning it's being reused.  You need to declare it within the loop:

```
$(function () {
    $(".wrapper").each(function (index) {
        var target = this;  //change is here

        $.ajax({
            url: getLink,
            data: 'AllData',
            async: false,
        }).done(function (data) {
                vm = new myViewModel(data);
                ko.applyBindings(vm, target);
        });           
    });
});
```

Having it declared outside of the loop means it's being overwritten on each iteration, so by the time the async calls come back, they're all attempting to bind to the same target element.

Comment: Thank you, as you saw in my edit I had target outside the loop. It didn't occur to me that declaring it globally was causing the issue.